# Instantly format a UITextView using AttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, macos, textview, uitextview

I'm developing a macOS rich-text editor that applies pre-defined style for each line of the text view.

To format the lines, I'm using `NSAttributedString`, then, I'm inserting that string into my `UITextView`. To make things easier, I'm using a tool called [SwiftRichString](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftRichString).

My code looks like below. It's straight-forward and works fine.

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftRichString
import AppKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Format the string
        let style = Style {
            $0.font = NSFont(name: "Arial", size: 20)
            $0.color = NSColor.black
            $0.alignment = .center
        }
        let attributedText = "Hello World!".set(style: style)

        // Add formatted string to the text view
        textView.textStorage?.append(attributedText)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

}
```

**Current situation:**

User is typing a formatted line. Then when user hits *Return* and types something, format of the new line returns back to the default style of the UITextView.

**What I want:**

User is typing a certain formatted line, then he hits *Return*. The next line **should** be formatted to another pre-defined style **on-the-go**.

**Example:**

1. User is typing the **Title** line. Current style is (Arial, bold, 20pt).
2. He hits *Return*.
3. Next line should be styled as **Normal** Text using a pre-defined style (Arial, 12pt).

**Important Note:**

In my above code, I was able to format the line easily because it's hard-coded. My real issue is, how can I instantly format the next line, because the next line will be entered by the user. The style should be applied to the next line before user begins writing it.

Comment: Maybe set the `typingAttributtes`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449487-typingattributes ?

Comment: Would you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I just figured out how to use `typingAttributtes` to solve this question (thanks to @Larme for the hint).

```
   // Define next attributes
   let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
       .foregroundColor: NSColor.red,
       .font: NSFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)!,
   ]
   
   // Assign attributes to the text view typing attributes
   textView.typingAttributes = attributes
```

Very easy!

Answer (score 1):

Pardon off topic. If you're making a text editor, you may consider using a table view, where each text line is a cell - this is extra work for you as a programmer but it'll boost the performance significantly. That's how Xcode editor is built.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you might use `optional func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618599-textviewdidchange

and after the change, just parse the text, find new lines, split them and apply all styling you want

Comment: `textViewDidChange` (and `textDidChange` for macOS) would not do much here, because I need to apply the new style _before_ user start typing next line.